# Catch insecure response error in mixed content situation

Tags: jquery, mixed-content

I noticed when I try to display data in an iframe of a modal popup from a site that uses http when application is running https, I get blank screen. Looking at browser console I noticed the message:

```
"Mixed content: The page at https://MyApp/SomePage/' was loaded over https. but requested an insecure HTMLHttpRequest endpoint 'http://TheOtherSite'. This request has been blocked, the content must be served over https'.
```

I have no control over "TheOtherSite" and "MyApp" must use https. So, instead of displaying a blank popup, I need to display something to tell the use why s/he is seeing blank screen.

I changed:

```
$(document).on('click', 'extLink', function () {
    var frametarget = $(this).attr('href');
    $('#lblModalTitle').text(blahblah');
    $('#modaliframe').attr("src", frametarget);  // Modal body has an iframe with id of "modaliframe"
}
```

to:

```
$(document).on('click', 'extLink', function () {
    var frametarget = $(this).attr('href');
    $('#lblModalTitle').text(blahblah');

    var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    request.open('GET', frametarget, true);

    request.onload = function () {
        $('#modaliframe').attr("src", request.responseText);
        console.log(request.responseText);
    };
    request.onerror = function () {
        console.log(request.responseText);
    };
    request.send();
}
```

But it always falls into .onerror where responseText is blank and status" is 0.

Is there any way I can catch this error and display it?

Comment: If the `http://TheOtherSite` URL is being provided by the user, you could simply check if the string the user provides starts with `http://`. If some other site is providing it, almost all browsers will reject mixed content, so you can, again, just check if the URL starts with `http://`, and if it does, display a warning to the user.

Comment: It is a list of printers' IP addresses and supplier only has access to printer info through http. If there is no way to catch the message regarding mixed content, your option seems viable.